# How to get int value from base64 encoded string if I know it should be a 32-bit/4-byte int?

Tags: encoding, binary, base64

These are the steps I think are necessary

- Remove `=` padding from end of base64 input
- Convert each character to its base64 char-index
- Convert each of these numerical char-indexes to binary
- Pad those binary words with leading `0`s until each is 6 bits (base64 requires 6 bits but not all had to be used)
- Take the first 4-bytes/32-bits of that new sequence and convert it to decimal (assuming unsigned int)

Is this the correct guide?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Just to add to Josef's comments, your question really needs some sample code (in any language) and also a few _input => expected output_ examples. As it stands your question is just hypothetical with no specific problem to be solved, and is therefore off topic. See [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) for more details.